# How can I change the scale labels in matplotlibs contourf method?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, label, contourf

I have created the image

[image]

using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def build_contour_plot(nu):
    plt.contourf(B, D, nu, 111)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.show()


b = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.001)
d = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.001)
B, D = np.meshgrid(b, d)
nu = np.ceil(np.minimum(B, D)*5)/5
build_contour_plot(nu)
```

How can I make the labels on the scale on the right-hand-side to be `[0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1]` instead of `[0.00, 0.11, ..., 0.99]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ticks` parameter of [`colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) accepts a list of ticks, or a `Locator` such as [`MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

def build_contour_plot(nu):
    plt.contourf(B, D, nu, 111)
    plt.colorbar(ticks=mticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]